# Steps for Bluetooth File Transfer implementation for Android

Tags: android

With BluetoothChat sample from Google sources as the base, what are the steps in implementing a file transfer function using that base code? I am trying to send a pdf or an image file (jpeg, jpg, png) to the other devices.

The chat functionality already works and I'm trying to implement a file transfer.

I can get the Uri and real file path (using PickIt library, ex path: storage/0/emulated/etc/etc) of the file that the user picked from the ACTION_GET_DOCUMENT intent. For the image file, I have found sources. They first convert it to a bitmap then to bytes and vice versa on the receiving device but haven't tried to do that yet. As for the pdf file, how would I implement it? I'm confused and questions similar to mine are mostly 7-10 years ago. Any help is appreciated. TIA!

P.S. I'm still new to Android development and I'm using Java.

Comment: Read and follow this documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth

Comment: Sure. But how would that help me if I have no idea how to implement what I need to do? Sure, I need some BluetoothSocket, ServerSocket, input and output streams in order to communicate but I need a reference flow. Just to follow how it's implemented.

Comment: well then this is example in java https://github.com/superssingh/Bluetooth-file-transfer-android-application-

Comment: Thanks, I've viewed that one before but he uses the Intent_ACTION_SEND. I think it's a simplified way? I'll try compiling that app tomorrow and see if it works and may be integrate it within my app.